# Collection insert if empty else update

Tags: meteor

This code displays a mainMenu with menuItems to click. "Template.mainMenu"
When menuItem is clicked, I need to store the value of the menuItem in a document but if the user clicks a different item, then I need to change the value and not create another document.

The code below is not updating the document with the new menuItem value. Thanks

```js
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

Template.mainMenu.helpers({
  menuItems: [
    {menuItem: "task1"},
    {menuItem: "task2"},
    {menuItem: "task3"},
    {menuItem: "task4"},
    {menuItem: "task5"},
    {menuItem: "task6"},
    {menuItem: "task7"}
  ]
});

Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': function (event) {
    var item = $(event.currentTarget).data('value');
    if (Tasks.find().count() === 0) {
      Tasks.insert({menuItem: item});
    } else {
      Tasks.update({_id: item._id} ,{$set: {menuItem: item}});
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upsert will update the id with the new value without inserting a new line. If the id you pass doesn't exist in the db, it will create a new one.

```
Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': function (event) {
    var item = $(event.currentTarget).data('value');
    Tasks.upsert({_id: item._id} ,{$set: {menuItem: item}});
  }
});
```

More info: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/upsert

Answer (score 0):

```
Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': function (event) {
    var item = $(event.currentTarget).data('value');
    Tasks.update({_id: item._id} ,{$set: {menuItem: item}},{upsert : true});
  }
});
```

This is the syntax, hope it will help :)